# Browsersession timeout

Tags: tomcat, spring-boot, firefox, spring-security, session-cookies

Sorry for the strange title but i do not quiet know where my problem originated from.

I am developing a Spring-Boot Application protected by Spring Security. It identifies users by a cookie called JSESSIONID which expires at the end of the "Session" (I do not know what session is meant by that.)

I have some users that login, use the application for some minutes, leave the browser-tab open for a couple of hours and the try to reuse the application but they are no longer recognized by the server and have to reauthenticate.

I have two ideas about the origin of the problem.

1. If the first request is send a couple of hours later the browser (firefox in that special case) forgot about the cookie (maybe because of a timeout of some kind) and did not include it in the request or
2. The cookie is still included in the request but the backend forgot about that session (maybe because of a configurable timeout)

I home you can help me find the problem and in the best case a way to tweak it.

Answer (score 0):

From what i understood from your question, i think you need to configure session management in your spring-boot application.

Remember-me authentication is a solution for remembering the identity of a user between sessions. Spring Security sends a cookie to browser, when user login to the application with remember-me option. This cookie is stored at browser side for a specific time period. Next time, when user logins to application, Spring security will check and validate the stored cookie and cause the automatic login if cookie is valid.

Spring Security provides two approaches for implementing remember-me -

> Hash-Based Token Approach - In this approach, username, expiration time, password and a private key are hashed and sent to browser as a token.
>
> Persistent Token Approach - In this approach, a database or other persistent storage mechanism is used to store the generated tokens.

Try to Google on how to implement these, you will get plenty of sources.

One more thing, you also need to set the session timeout properties in your application.properties and configure it as per your requirement.

```
server.session.timeout=# time in seconds
```